# Как поменять язык на клавиатуре и инлайн кнопках в телеграм боте Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть бот в телеграм и я уже сделал функцию выбора языка и всё работает коректно, но я не знаю как поменять язык на кнопках если они созданы в другом файле `keyboards.py` и записаны вот так:

```
markup_games = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
lot = types.KeyboardButton('первое')
num = types.KeyboardButton('второе')
cases = types.KeyboardButton('третье')
markup_games.add(lot, num, cases)

markup_work_admin = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
work_admin_trx = types.InlineKeyboardButton(' Баланс TRX', callback_data='work_admin_trx')
work_admin_usd = types.InlineKeyboardButton(' Баланс USDT', callback_data='work_admin_usd')
markup_work_admin.add(work_admin_trx, work_admin_usd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для каждой клавиатуры можно создать функцию, которая будет ее генерировать, что-то вроде:

```
def markup_work_admin(lang: str):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    # заполняем клавиатуру кнопками нужного языка (опираясь на lang)
    # кнопки с разными языками можно записать заранее в отдельном файле, либо через gettext тот же
    return markup
```

если не нравится, что при каждом вызове функции генерируется новый экземпляр клавы, можно добавить кеш в виде декоратора **cache** или **lru_cache** из **functools**

```
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache
def markup_work_admin(lang: str):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    # заполняем клавиатуру кнопками нужного языка (опираясь на lang)
    # кнопки с разными языками можно записать заранее в отдельном файле, либо через gettext тот же
    return markup
```